# Delete photo from custom photo album ios

Tags: ios

I am working in IOS app which load photos from custom album. Now I need to delete photo from custom album. Is there any ways to delete photos.

Thanks in advance
Varadharaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, You cannot delete any photo saved in the User Album. Apple didn't provided APIs to do that.

Comment: @user1960389 Please mark my answer as correct. If you find this information helpful. Thanks